# TypeError: first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by, package

I have a dataset, and i'm using Groupby and transform along with First to get the results. But it is throwing above error, please let me know how to go about it.

Input :

```
 Column A  Column B
 18         1
 18         1
 20         3
 20         1
 20         1
 24         2
 24         1
 24         1
 18         3
 18         1
 18         1
 18         1
 25         1
 25         1
 25         1
```

Output :

```
 Column A  Column B
 18         1
 18         1
 20         3
 20         3
 20         3
 24         2
 24         2
 24         2
 18         3
 18         3
 18         3
 18         3
 25         1
 25         1
 25         1
```

Right now I'm using :

```
  df['Column B'] = df.groupby(df['Column A'].ne(df['Column A'].shift()).cumsum())['Column B'].transform('first')
```

Error :

```
   File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2210, in transform
   res = wrapper(group)

   File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2203, in <lambda>
   wrapper = lambda x: getattr(x, func)(*args, **kwargs)

   TypeError: first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: works for me, which version of pandas do you use?

Comment: I'm trying in Juypter Notebook, and Azure ML.

Comment: Can you show the output of `pandas.__version__`?